# Generating a large sample of 10 x10 symmetric matrices

Tags: matrix, function-construction

I am currently having some issues with Mathematica. I have a 10x10 symmetric matrix with the diagonal entries removed and labeled as "z".

I now want to create a command that generates a sample of greater than 500 matrices that have this characteristic.

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Waie, welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please add some code to your question, otherwise we'll find it very hard to help you!

Comment: This is a bit silly but it works :-) `Table[mat1 = Normal@SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> z}, {10, 10}]`; mat = ImageData@RandomImage[1, {10, 10}] // # + Transpose[#] &;  mat1 + mat /. z + _ -> z,{500}]`

Comment: @chris Why not `RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 10}]` instead of `ImageData@RandomImage[1, {10, 10}]`?

Comment: Apologies for not adding the code... 
I have generated a matrix starting from a previous one with the command:

> ReplacePart[[1/2 (A + Transpose[A])], {i_, i_} -> z] // MatrixForm

Now, I want to generate a sample of other 500 matrices of the same form... (in order to plot the analyse the behaviour of the eigenvalues better).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Table[A = 
  RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0.5, 0.2], {10, 10}];
 B = 1/2 (A + Transpose@A) UnitBox[IdentityMatrix[10]] + 
   DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[z, 10]];
 B, 500]
```

Comment: how do I get 500 matrices like this? Simply by using Table[...]?
Also, instead of using RandomReal[...], I need to use a symmetric matrix that follows a normal distribution. 
My starting point is: "ReplacePart[[1/2 (A + Transpose[A])], {i_, i_} -> z] // MatrixForm" and from this I need to generate 500 other matrices.

Comment: A is a matrix generated with a normal distribution.

Comment: The mean is 0.5 and the variance is 0.2.

Comment: See my edit. I hope this is what you are looking for..

Comment: @Waie "Also, instead of using RandomReal[...], I need to use a symmetric matrix that follows a normal distribution." Really, do you have a faint idea how much of other people's lifetime you consume? What about presenting _all_ relevant information in the first place? What about giving at least _some_ relevant code to start from? Moreover, you can **edit** your question at any time in order to improve its quality.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I would say they guilt is 'only' 80% on OP's side. Effortless questions should be closed not answered, exactly because of problems with follow up wishes like this. Now I have to deal with multiple flags saying that your comment was unfriendly, which I dismissed of course. +1 to you Okkes, I don't want to discourage you. Just saying what to be aware of.

Comment: @Kuba I have to admit that in case of severe boredom, I also tend to answer such questions. Learnt my lesson. I apologize for any inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that will generate random symmetric matrices with their diagonals zeroed out (n is the size of the matrix).

```
f[n_] := (mat = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, n}]; 
          mat + Transpose[mat] - 2 DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal[mat]]);
```

To generate 500 such matrices, call this function 500 times:

```
Table[f[10],{i,500}]
```

or use Map:

```
f[#] & /@ ConstantArray[10, 500]
```

Comment: It seems that I get a vector of 10 entries rather than a 10x10 matrix. I need to get 500 10x10 matrices..

Comment: If you look at the dimensions of the output, it is {500,10,10} which means 500 10x10 matrices.